# Fade-in transition of nodes in Cytoscape js

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, cytoscape.js

I have been trying to make added nodes and edges in my diagram appear "smoothly" using animate() to gradually change their opacity! But I am missing something in the way the animation works, so I can't make it work like it' supposed to! I've initialized both the nodes' and edges' opacity to 0 like this:

```
 'selector': 'node[id*="local"]', // local endpoint nodes
            'style': {
                'shape': 'rectangle',
                'width': '50px',
                'height': '50px',
                'opacity': 0,
                'background-color': 'white',
                'background-image': 'assets/db.png',
                'background-fit': 'cover cover',
                'label': 'data(id)',
                'text-margin-y': '10px',
                'text-valign': 'bottom',
                'text-halign': 'center',
                'text-outline-color': '#ccc',
                'text-outline-width': 3
            }
        }, {
            'selector': 'edge[target*="local"]',
            'style': {
                'width': 3,
                'opacity': 0,
                'line-color': '#1e11c2',
                'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
                'font-family': 'cursive',
                'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
            }

        },
```

and I attempt to change them in the following way:

```
 cy.nodes("[id*='local']").animate({'style': {'opacity': 0.2}}, {'duration': 600}).delay(200).animate({'style': {'opacity': 0.6}}, {'duration' : 600}).animate({'style': {'opacity': 1}}, {'duration': 600});
 cy.edges("[target*='local']").animate({'style': {'opacity': 0.2}}, {'duration': 600}).delay(200).animate({'style': {'opacity': 0.6}}, {'duration' : 600}).animate({'style': {'opacity': 1}}, {'duration': 600});
```

With these lines, the graph elements don't even appear in the graph. Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I could make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems almost ok, this is what I use to achieve this (maybe use this syntax and spacing for better readability):

```
currentElements.animate({              // you can create a collection with edges and nodes for this
    style: { opacity: yourValue},
    duration: 600,
    easing: 'ease-in-sine'
}).delay(200).animate({
    style: { opacity: yourNextValue},
    duration: 600,
    easing: 'ease-in-sine'
}).delay(0).animate({
    style: { opacity: yourLastValue},
    duration: 600,
    easing: 'ease-in-sine'
});
```